# Laravel set validation message to Array Field?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-validation

How to set custom validation message to array file like.

```
$validationRules = [
    'attrtitle[]' => 'required|max:255',
];
```

i try code for set message but not working.

```
protected $messages = [
    'attrtitle[]:required' => 'Please Select Attributes.'
];

// OR //

protected $messages = [
    'attrtitle:required' => 'Please Select Attributes.'
];

my html field for attrtitle is

<select name='attrtitle[]' multiple>
  <option value=''>Select Value</option>
  <option value='1'>1</option>
  <option value='2'>2</option>
  <option value='3'>3</option>
</select>
```

i try both but not working how can i set custom message for attrtitle field please help thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just you need to add `.` instead of `:` sign like.

and use this :

```
protected $messages = [
    'attrtitle[].required' => 'Please Select Attributes.'
];
```

Comment: Sorry for being offtopic, but it would be perfect to stick index number into message itself... like Please Select Attributes (array index number). Do you have an Idea how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$messages = [
    'attrtitle.required' => 'Please Select Attributes.'
];
```

In your controller and then add it to your validate method like this :

```
$this->validate($request, $validationRules, $messages);
```